# Chrome won't show math formulas

Tags: google-chrome, math, browser

The math formula won't compile properly in Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html

All I see is just the raw formula:

> f(x; \frac{1}{\beta}) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp(-\frac{x}{\beta}),

The mathJax Plugin is also not working on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of the documentation actually works just as expected:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html?highlight=exponential#numpy.random.exponential